# ProSavage DDR video drivers not working

Tags: lubuntu, hardware, gpu-driver

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and everything went well except for one little thing: general display speed sucks! So, looking around on Google, I've found that VIA ProSavage DDR display drivers may be a little tricky to install.

Executing this code in a terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

I get this result:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED  
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: VT8375 [ProSavage8 KM266/KL266]
   vendor: S3 Graphics Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm agp agp-2.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=255 mingnt=4
   resources: memory:ff980000-ff9fffff memoria:d0000000-d7ffffff memoria:ff970000-ff97ffff
```

Also, here is my Xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "gfxcard"
    Driver      "savage"
    Option      "NoAccel" "True"
    Option      "ShadowFB" "Enable"
    Option      "UseTiming1024"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen 0"
    Device      "gfxcard"
    Monitor     "Monitor 0"
    DefaultDepth    16
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor 0"
    Option      "DPMS" "Disable"
EndSection
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: S3Graphics lost the war with NVidia and ATI.  What you have is what you'll get.  Nothing more.  Sorry!  :(

Comment: I know. But I still have to solve this. My inner geek want's to know what I can do. Thx anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry to be the harbinger of bad news (and please, drop me a note in a week or two or when you *do get an answer*), but AFAIK: **There's nothing you can do on top of what you’ve done already**